# How to pass 1 or more arrays of 4 strings to request in swagger?

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

Basically, I want to set up swagger to accept something like this in the request

```
[
    {
        "input_id": "",
        "city": "",
        "state": "",
        "zipcode": "20500"
    },
    {
        "input_id": "",
        "city": "Cupertino",
        "state": "CA",
        "zipcode": ""
    },
    {
        "input_id": "",
        "city": "",
        "state": "",
        "zipcode": "95014"
    },
    {
        "input_id": "Apple",
        "city": "Cupertino",
        "state": "ca",
        "zipcode": "90210"
    }
]
```

I am having some issues with my current setup

```
  - name: testing
    in: query
    description: 'zip request info'
    type: array
    items:
      type: object
      properties:
        input_id:
          type: string
        city:
          type: string
        state:
          type: string
        zipcode:
          type: string
```

This sets the `POST` url to access these items like this
...`testing[0][city]=burbank&testing[0][state]=ca`...

When I want to access them like this
...`city=burbank&state=ca`... for each city/state/zipcode/input_id pair.

UPDATE:

my new setup is working, besides errors thrown by swagger. It works though!

```
    - name: City/State pair or ZIP Code
      in: body
      description: 1 or more
      type: array
      items:
        minimum: 1
        type: object
        properties:
          input_id:
            type: string
            description: A unique identifier for this address used in your application; this field will be copied into the output
          city:
            type: string
            description: The city name
          state:
            type: string
            description: State name or abbreviation
          zipcode:
            type: string
            description: The 5-digit ZIP Code
```

If anyone can find a better solution than this (without errors) let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was almost correct in my edit. I just needed to add in `schema:` on the line before adding `type: array`

```
name: 'City/State pair or ZIP Code'
in: body
description: 1 or more
schema:
  type: array
  items:
    type: object
    properties:
      input_id:
        type: string
        description: A unique identifier for this address used in your application; this field will be copied into the output
      city:
        type: string
        description: The city name
      state:
        type: string
        description: State name or abbreviation
      zipcode:
        type: string
        description: 'The 5-digit ZIP Code'
```

This works and has no errors. I can add multiple objects to my array so it will post in the format I want